# Not sure about & operator

Tags: c

I tried to make a simple circuit to toggle a LED every 30 seconds. The Timer/Counter Interrupt Flag Register (TIFR) is an 8 bit register with the following spec:

[image: image of bit layout of 8 bit Timer Interrupt Flag Register]

Note that this is a typical AVR chip that doesn't matter for the purpose of this question. When a timer overflow occurs the bit TOV0 will be set to one by hardware. This lets me know the status of the timer. Then I will clear it by writing a logic 1 to the TIFR register. Here's the code:

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#define LED PB0

int main(void)
{
uint16_t timerOverflowCount=0;

DDRB=0xff; //configure PORTD as output  
TCNT0=0x00; //set counter to 0
TCCR0B=(1<<CS00) | (1<<CS02);


   while(1)
   {
       while ((TIFR & 0x01) == 0);

       TCNT0 = 0x00;
       TIFR=0x01;
       timerOverflowCount++;

       if (timerOverflowCount>=919)
       {
           PORTB ^= (0x01 << LED);
           timerOverflowCount=0;
       }
   }

}
```

What I don't understand about this code is the condition check of the second `while`:

```
while ((TIFR & 0x01) == 0);
```

Obviously, it looks like the loop causes a delay until a counter overflow occurs. Then the control passes to the next statements.

I'm not an experienced C user so I don't understand what the `&` operand does in the `while` statement's condition check. My understanding is that in C `&` is an address-of-operator which finds the address of a typical object. I am not sure of the meaning of the `&` operator here.

Comment: `&` is a bitwise AND operator.

Comment: A loooong question that can be solved by a simple search through some C operators documentation.

Comment: *Unary* `&` is address-of operator. What you see here is a *binary* `&`, which is a completely different story. It has nothing to do with unary `&`.

Comment: `while ((TIFR & 0x01) == 0);` this is something I personally hate. Who remembers what is in the bit 0 of the TIFR register. do not save your fingers `&&` keyboard - write something more human readable `while ((TIFR & (1 << TOV0)) == 0);` or `while (!(TIFR & (1 << TOV0)));` Avoid `DAC1 -> CR = 0x34674534;` - I saw similar on the STM forum asking - what is wrong in my configuration.

Answer (score 4):

It's a bitwise AND. Here, it’s used to filter out all but the last bit:

```
nnnnnnnn
00000001  (0x01)
-------- &
0000000n
```

This means that `while ((n & 0x01) == 0)` will loop as long as the rightmost bit is *not* set.

Answer (score 0):

`&` is the bitwise and operator: the expression `TIFR & 1` evaluates to `1` if and only if the least significant bit of `TIFR` is `1`.

The full statement `while ((TIFR & 0x01) == 0);` is called a busy loop: it repeats the test as long as is fails. The body of the `while` loop is the empty statement `;`. `TIFR` should be defined as an expression that returns the value of some hardware register that will eventually have its low order bit set, typically the `volatile` qualified address for the memory mapped hardware register.

The program will run at 100% CPU, draining the battery, waiting for this value to change, hence the expression *busy wait*.  It might be better to use a `nanosleep()` function call to wait efficiently in the body of this loop.

Answer (score 0):

The `&` operator has a few uses. In this case, it operates on two pieces of data. This is very similar to the AND gate. It outputs 1 if both inputs are 1, otherwise it outputs 0.

In your example, we use the `&` operator to get the status of a certain bit:

```
nnnnnnnn
00000001
-------- &
0000000n
```

An example: say the value of nnnnnnnn was 00001011. We only want the status of the last bit, so we `&` this value with 00000001. Since the logical AND operation will output a 1 only if the inputs are both 1, `&`ing our value with 00000001 will output 00000001 if, and only if, the last bit is 1.

In C the `&` operator can also be used in front of a pointer to indicate that you want the value of the pointer, not the value contained by the pointer (that'd be with  `*`) These two differ in syntax.

```
0xNN & 0xKK                        /* Logical AND */
uint32_t valueOfPointer = &ptr;    /* Value of pointer */
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at a C Operator Precedence chart such as this one, [C Operator Precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence), you will notice that there are several symbols, and `&` is one of those, which mean different things depending on the context the symbol appears.

And in some cases more than one symbol is combined in order to create an operator for example `+=` or `<<` so I can understand why you might be running into some confusion.

With a `while` statement the C compiler is going to look at what is in between the parenthesis and try its best to turn that into a statement that expresses either `true` (represented by a non-zero value though an explicitly boolean statement will return a value of one) or `false` (represented by a value of zero).

So the statement `while ((TIFR & 0x01) == 0);` is a `while` loop that has a condition but no actual body. The result is that this loop will continue looping until such time as the condition changes from non-zero (`true`) to zero (`false`). This condition will be met when the register's least significant bit becomes a one and the bitwise And between the register and the value of 0x01 becomes non-zero.

The C compiler sees the use of the symbol ampersand (`&`) in this context as the bitwise And operator. So what the machine code generated is to perform a bitwise And of the hexadecimal constant 1 with the value of what TIFR represents.

In your case TIFR represents the Timer/Counter Interrupt Flag Register so what the condition is doing is performing a bitwise And of 0x01 with the register. I assume that the low order bit of the register, the TOV0 bit in your diagram, will be set to zero or off until some external event happens which then sets the bit to one or on. When this happens the bitwise And evaluates to non-zero and the logical equality fails exiting the loop.

So long as the TOV0 bit is off the bitwise And with 0x01 will result in a zero value which the `while()` then compares to a value of zero. As soon as the bit is set to one or on, the bitwise And will result in a non-zero value which the `while()` compares to zero at which point the loop will exit since the compare fails.

**Unary versus Binary `&` Operator**

The basic rule for the single ampersand (`&`) is that when it is a unary operator then it is seen as being the Address Of operator. When it is seen as a binary operator then it is seen as being the bitwise And operator.

If it is used with one of the assignment operator variations as in `&=` then it is seen as evaluating the right side and then take that value and perform a bitwise And with what is on the left side of the operator and assigning the resulting value to the left side variable.

So some examples.

```
int myInt = 1;
int *pInt = &myInt;      // unary operator so this is the Address Of use
int myInt2 = myInt & 3;  // binary operator so this is the bitwise And use
int aInt[] = {1,3,2,4,5,7,8};
int *pLast = &aInt[sizeof(aInt)/sizeof(aInt[0]) - 1];  // unary operator so Address Of use

while (pLast >= &aInt[0] && ! (*pLast & 0x01)) pLast--;
if (pLast >= aInt) {
    *pLast &= ~0x01;  // clear the least significant bit of value pointed to
}
```

Notice in the while statement we are using the ampersand as both the Address Of operator and the bitwise And operator. Plus we are using two ampersands, `&&`, for the logical And operator. And we are also using the bitwise And assignment operator, `&=`, in the body of the `if` statement (and there can not be any white space between one symbol and the next so `&=` is valid but `& =` is not).

What this loop does is iterates through the array from the end until an odd numbered value is found, a value that does have the least significant bit set. If such a value is found then we turn the least significant bit off using the bitwise And assignment.